# @Autowired AuthenticationManager is null (JavaFX + Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, javafx

I have a JavaFX desktop application that requires login authentication with database using Spring Security. The AuthenticationManager is not getting autowired properly and throws `NullPointerException`. I reused most of this code from web app where this is working properly, but won't here.

LoginController.java

```
@Component
public class LoginController{

private boolean userAuthenticated = true;
@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@FXML
public void login() {
        Authentication authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            emailField.getText(), passField.getText());
    try {
        System.out.println(authenticationManager);
        authToken = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);  // throws NullPointer
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

applicationContext.xml

```xml
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
<context:component-scan>
    <bean id="LoginController" class="controller.LoginController">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Most probably you are loading a FXML file that specifies `fx:controller="controller.LoginController"`. Unfortunately this instantiates the `LoginController` through the FXML mechanism, ignoring Spring. You can check it out by setting a breakpoint to the constructor of the `LoginController`, it will be initialized twice (once from Spring, once from FXML). A solution is to remove the `fx:controller` attribute and specify the controller passing the instance you get from Spring to `FXMLLoader.setController()`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos what should I pass as an argument to `setController()`?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos i tried doing `loader.setController(appContext.getBean("loginController"));` but I now get nupppointer on appContext that is also autowired the same way authenticationManager is

Comment: You probably have to revisit the way you are loading your views. Sorry for the 2 "probablies", but there is not enough information to provide a definite answer. Maybe if you could elaborate on how you are loading your views?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos this is my main method that loads login view. http://pastebin.com/szNCKHqD Next views after login are loaded using this framework https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1 but only after successful login so that framework is not relevant i think as it is in separate window with own controllers

Comment: Still cannot say, sorry. The principle is that you have to make sure that the controller is loaded from Spring, *then* injected by FXML - using `setController()`. The `.fxml` file must *not* define its controller.